# Method for Wrapping Around a Design into a Book Cover form?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, 3d, book, product-design

Is there any method for wrapping a design into a book cover form (3D-like)?
I mean wrapping a single rectangular design to cover & spine & back.

I'm using Adobe Illustrator CS5.

Comment: there are lots of method for the same..depends on which application you are using.please be specific

Comment: Adobe Illustrator CS5

Comment: Just checking: you mean you already have a flat design and want to show how it'll look on the finished item?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your design is raster, AI won't allow you to distort it. You'd have to accomplish this in PS. However, if your design is vector, you can use this technique:

http://livedocs.adobe.com/en_US/Illustrator/13.0/help.html?content=WS714a382cdf7d304e7e07d0100196cbc5f-646d.html

1. Select one or more objects.
2. Select the Free Transform tool .
3. Start dragging a corner handle on the bounding box (not a side handle), and then do one of the following:
   Hold down Ctrl (Windows) or Command (Mac OS) until the selection is at the desired level of distortion.
   Hold down Shift+Alt+Ctrl (Windows) or Shift+Option+Command (Mac OS) to distort in perspective.

[image]

Comment: There is a similar method available in CS5 which is the [perspective drawing tool](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/illustrator/cs/using/WS25dc2c49b27459df-4aaea6de12476f87539-8000.html).